# Carregar conteúdo RTF em componente HTML

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

Estou usando a API [SCEditor](https://www.sceditor.com/) para disponibilizar um editor de texto na página, mas preciso preencher ele (setar o valor) com o conteúdo de uma string em RTF. Fiz da seguinte forma, mas já deu erro nas aspas...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    var textarea = document.getElementById('example');
    sceditor.create(textarea, {
        format: 'xhtml',
        style: 'minified/themes/content/default.min.css'
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não funciona pois o plugin SCEditor cria um `iframe` para exibição do conteúdo do `textarea`. Você não pode alterar diretamente o `textarea`, ou se fizer, deverá atualizar também o plugin `sceditor`.

Para atualizar o textarea juntamente com o sceditor você deve recuperar a instância que o objeto cria e usar `val()` para inserir os valores e `updateOriginal()` para atualizar o objeto DOM textarea:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('example');
sceditor.create(textarea, {
    format : 'xhtml',
    style: 'minified/themes/content/default.min.css'
});
sceditor.instance(textarea).val("string que você quer inserir aqui");
sceditor.instance(textarea).updateOriginal(); // atualiza o DOM textarea
```

Comment: E o erro "Expected hexadecimal digit" se refere a quê?

Comment: Qual editor você está usando? Ao que parece ele está interpretando algum valor da string como hexadecimal, esse erro ocorre no navegador também?... Os hexadecimais possuem um padrão unicode como `\uXXXX` e alguma parte do valor da string deve estar parecido com este padrão, por exemplo `\u82Yu` (O que ocasionaria o erro, pois em hexadecimal não existe Y nem u). Isso ocorre por causa das `backslashes` que servem para escapar os valores da string.

Comment: [Aqui tem](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/scripting/javascript/misc/expected-hexadecimal-digit) uma explicação mais detalhada. Em destaque, leia a parte *Observação*.

Comment: A string que preciso inserir no wysiwyg contém RTF. Inseri conforme a resposta, mas o resultado foi a própria string, como se o wysiwyg não tivesse interpretado o RTF.

Comment: Talvez você tenha que converter o texto RTF para HTML, como [nessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862330/need-a-wysiwyg-web-editor-for-the-rtf-format). Pesquisei no Google e há uma [biblioteca no Github  em javascript](https://github.com/iarna/rtf-to-html) que consegue realizar essa conversão, embora eu não tenha testado.